# Unable to validate Nigerian number

Tags: python, function

I created a function to check if the value is a phone number but when i tried calling it, it displays invalid token

```py
from sys import *

def is_PhoneNumber(number):
    if number.isdecimal():
        pass
    else:
        print("This is not a number at all")
        exit()
    if number[:2] not in list(range(70, 91)):
        print("This is not a Nigerian phone number")
        exit()
    else:
        pass
    if len(number) != 10:
        print("Its not a Nigerian phone number")
    else:
        pass


    print("This is a phone number")

is_PhoneNumber(09064764777)
```

Comment: isdecimal requires a string as input.

Comment: numbers cannot start with 0, and in your case i would change the number to string. Also, there is no isdecimal() method for numbers (longs).

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't think `number[:2] not in list(range(70, 91)):` is going to work because it's checking for a string slice against an integer list. Try `int(number[:2]) in range(70, 91)`, although logically it looks like this will not be true, so more clarification could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a number to that function, instead `isdigit` is a builtin function for string. Try using `is_PhoneNumber("09064764777")`

---

***NOTE:***
With python 3.7.3, you can now 'type hint' your code.
In order to avoid these confusional `type mismatch`, you can hint the type of the vars.

This code will still run over python 3.7.3, and your IDE will help you to recognize/remember the type of the variable.
***NOTE:***
Function like isalpha,isdigit,is_something (like your is_PhoneNumber), usually return a boolean value for recognize if the data in input 'is or not' what the function check.
Your code can be tweaked as following:

```py
from sys import *


def is_PhoneNumber(number: str) -> bool:
    print("is_PhoneNumber | Analyzing number {}".format(number))
    if not number.isdigit():
        print("is_PhoneNumber | String {} is not a number".format(number))
        return False
    if number[:2] not in list(range(70, 91)):
        print("is_PhoneNumber | This is not a Nigerian phone number")
        return False

    if len(number) != 10:
        print("Its not a Nigerian phone number")
        return False

    print("This is a Nigerian phone number")
    return True


is_PhoneNumber("09064764777")
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to put a double inverted commas while calling a number(is_PhoneNumber("09064764777")) so the compiler takes your number as integer and in defining the function , you use string functions in if-else condition which gives you a token error.